# Oblect Orient Program Class Structure --- Design Problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, class, oop

The question I have is a design question rather than a technical question. I am building an application in which its main feature is to allow user to select a Slack channel and a folder of images, and upload them to the chosen channel using Slack Web Client API. While that is the main feature, I plan to implement other features into the application that will improve usability. When I started working on the project, I wrote the code in a procedural "way" just to get the proof of concept working, but not that I have been successful with that, I am currently in the process of refactoring my code. I was to employ a more Object-Oriented approach to the refactoring, as well as any development of the application going forward. I have already refactored the code that actually uploads the file to Slack into a class, but I am know wondering if I am going about this in a way that makes sense. I will give an example two features of the application that I have created so far to better explain:

**"Get Channels" Feature**
One such feature is the "Get Channels" feature with fetches the available Slack channels from the Slack API and stores them in an array so that the channels can be displayed on the front end so the user can pick which channel, instead of them having to set it in an environment variable. This code has not been refactored for OOP yet:

```
app.get("/api/getChannels", (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
  client.conversations.list()
    .then((result) => {
      let allChannels: string[][] = result.channels?.map((channel) => [`${channel.id}`, `${channel.name}`]) ?? [];
      console.log(allChannels);
      response.json(allChannels);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      response.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to retrieve channels" });
    });
});
```

**"Upload To Slack" Feature**
The "Upload To Slack" feature is the main feature, and uses the Slack API to upload the files, allowing for specification of file name, file, channel, etc. As mentioned before, the code for this has already been refactored, and encapsulated in a "FileUploader" class with various methods:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';
dotenv.config();

export default class FileUploader {
  private client: WebClient;
  private sdCardPath: string;
  private dirName: string;
  private channel: string;
  private absDir: string;


  constructor(dirName: string, channel: string) {
    this.client = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_TOKEN);
    this.sdCardPath = process.env.SD_CARD_PATH ?? '';
    this.dirName = dirName;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.absDir = path.join(this.sdCardPath, this.dirName);
  }

  async processFilesAndUpload(): Promise<void> {
    const files: string[] = await this.readFilesFromDirectory();
    const sortedFiles: string[] = this.filterAndSortFiles(files);
  
    for (const fileName of sortedFiles) {
      await this.uploadFileToSlackChannel(fileName, this.absDir);
      // Introduce a delay of, for example, 2.5 second between uploads
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2500));
    }
  }

  private async readFilesFromDirectory(): Promise<string[]> {
    try {
      return await fs.promises.readdir(this.absDir);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error reading directory: ${err}`);
      throw err;
    }
  }

  private filterAndSortFiles(files: string[]): string[] {
    const pattern: RegExp = /^IMG_.+\.JPG$/;
    const filteredFiles: string[] = files.filter((file: string) => pattern.test(file));
    return filteredFiles.sort();
  }

  private async uploadFileToSlackChannel(fileName: string, filePath:string): Promise<void> {
    try {
     await this.client.files.uploadV2({
       channel_id: this.channel,
       initial_comment: "Some Initial Comment",
       file: fs.createReadStream(path.join(filePath, fileName)),
       filename: fileName,
     });
     console.log(`Uploaded ${fileName} to Slack`);
   } catch (error) {
     if (error.code === 'slack_error_code') {
       console.error(`Error uploading ${fileName} to Slack: ${error.message}`);
     } else {
       console.error(`Unexpected error: ${error}`);
     }
     throw error;
   } 
 }
}
```

The class is exported and instantiated in a POST endpoint:

```
app.post("/api/uploadFiles", (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
  try {
    const dirName: string = "Some DirName";
    const channel: string ="Some Channel"; // Test Channel
    
    const fileUploader = new FileUploader(dirName, channel);
    fileUploader.processFilesAndUpload();
    response.status(200).json({message: "Files Uploaded Successfully!"})
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`Error uploading files: ${error}`);
    response.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
```

Features I have planned for the future would also really on the response object from the Slack API just like the "Get Channels" feature, and all the features would share some data such as the API token for example. My question now is what is the best way to go about creating the code in a way that is Object Oriented and would allow for scalability as I proceed. I am not very familiar with Object Oriented programming, and while I could just "spaghetti code" my way through the rest of the project and just claim it works, I would rather do it in a more organized way, and am looking for a bit of guidance in that regard. Should I keep the one class approach, and just keep adding methods to it? Should I break the classes up, and have them interact with each other instead? Or would I be better off abandoning the attempt at OOP all together?

I have read articles, forum threads, and watched Youtube videos all about the OOP design but I can seem to wrap my head around how to approach this. I know that there are many ways to design an application and I know not to expect a concrete "this is the only way you should do it" answer, but rather guidance on which direction to take when planning the design. If any clarification is needed, feel free to ask. Any contribution/help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: This type of question is off-topic on SO. It’s also not clear what the **specific** issue is *(noting that JS is OOP whether or not you’re using classes)*. Knowing what makes sense requires context *(technical and otherwise)* and there’s no generic answer.